# How to pass parameter to model function from view?

Tags: php, laravel

I have tree structure of categories. Now I have to display only that categories which is not applied in a particular business.

Code in Controller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        try
        {
            $id=Crypt::decrypt($id);
            $business=Business::findOrFail($id);
            $business_contact_details=BusinessContactDetails::where('business_id',$id)->select('contact_no','id')->get();
            $business_working_hours=BusinessWorkingHours::where('business_id',$id)->get();
            $business_categories=BusinessCategories::leftJoin('categories','categories.id','=','category_id')->where('business_id',$id)->where('categories.parent_id','0')->select('categories.name as name','approved','category_id','business_categories.id as id')->get();
            $categories = Categories::where('parent_id', '=', 0)->get();
            return view('admin.businesses.edit',compact('business','business_contact_details','business_working_hours','categories','category_counter','business_categories'));
        }
        catch(DecryptException $e)
        {
            return view('errors.404');
        }
    }
```

Code in Model

```
public function subChilds(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Categories','parent_id','id')->whereNotExists(function($query){
            $query->from('business_categories')->whereRaw('categories.id=business_categories.category_id')->where('business_id',2);
        });
    }
```

Code in edit View

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                            <ul id="tree1">
                                @foreach($categories as $category)
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{$category->id}}" name="categories[]"> 
                                        &nbsp;{{ $category->name }}
                                        @if(count($category->subChilds($business->id)))
                                            @include('admin.businesses.manageChildSub',['subChilds' => $category->subChilds($business->id)])
                                        @endif
                                    </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Code in manageChildSub View

```
<ul>
    @foreach($subChilds as $child)
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{$child->id}}" name="categories[]">
            &nbsp;{{ $child->name }}
            @if(count($child->childs))
                @include('manageChildSub',['subChilds' => $child->subChilds($business->id)])
            @endif
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Here, You can see that I have passed business_id as 2, but I have to pass it as my current business ID. Basically I need to call the model function with ID.

After changing to this, I am not getting any subcategories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public function subChilds($business_id){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Categories','parent_id','id')
                ->whereNotExists(function($query) use ($business_id){
                     $query->from('business_categories')
                     ->whereRaw('categories.id=business_categories.category_id')
                     ->where('business_id', $business_id);
    });
}
```

Comment: I know this. But I don't know that, how do I pass the business_id to this function.

Comment: You already calling with `$category->subChilds($business->id)`

Comment: By doing this I am not able to get any subcategories.

Comment: try `$category->subChilds($business->id)->get()`